# If a library is targeting .NET Standard 2.0 is my only option to use Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

If I am using a library that aims to **only** target .Net Standard 2.0 **and** I am using the .NET Framework (not .NET Core) version of the library which is 4.61 ([Reference Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard))

Am I now "required" to have Visual Studio 2017 15.3 to use this? Or am I still able to use Visual Studio 2015 considering that I only want to use .NET Framework 4.61?

Answer (score 2):

So following on from where [@Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860073/223742) put me on the right path...

If you see the comment by [Appu George](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/#div-comment-341555) it ***should*** be possible to consume a .NET Standard 2.0 .NET Framework within VS2015 if you have:

- NuGet Client 3.60 [Download](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)
- .NET Standard Build Support [Download](https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx)

@Kobi if you want to add the above to your answer I would be happy to mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should work for you. I didn't find official documentation, but I did find some comments.

[Immo Landwerth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/#div-comment-339205), product manager at Microsoft, 2017-08-14 (emphasis added):

> **Consumption is, but you need an updated NuGet client which AFAIK will ship soon**. If you want to build .NET Standard 2.0 libraries you need to use VS 2017 (15.3). You could, however, also just use the command line until you can upgrade your VS.

Comment: I am only consuming the library, but I guess then that means I would still need VS2017 anyway.

Comment: @TheEdge - then I misunderstood, I thought you are writing this library. I think it is possible by updating NuGet, I'll try to find data on that.